# Unable to parse data in R

Tags: r, time-series

Hi I"m going a Time series analysis, and I cannot figure out the cause of

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:10:10: unexpected input
```

I have tried to rewrite my code(shown below), but I keep on getting the same error

```
set.seed(1000)
N <- 100
t <- 1:N
x1 <- 2 * t + rnorm(N, 0.2, 4)
m1 <- lm(x1 ~ t)
summary(m1)
y1 <- x1 — m1$coefficients[2] * t
```

The code above gives me the error I have quoted above. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to update it with the solution. I needed parentheses for it to work.

```
y1 <- x1 — (m1$coefficients[2] * t)
```