# Need Help in Creating A Function

Tags: r, function

I have created a function and I keep getting the following error

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
```

Based on previous question, this error is usually associated with a missing parenthesis. However, I have check is numerous times, and I cannot see the missing parenthesis

the function is shown below

```
function(x,y){
    year.col<-select_if(x,is.numeric)
    year.col[is.na(year.col)]<-0
    year.col[year.col==0]<-paste(y)
    updated.dataset<-cbind(x,year.col)
    return(year.col)
    }
```

Sample dataframe

```
A   B   C   D   E  F  G  H 
foo T   S   K   0  0  0  NA 
foo T   A   j   0  NA 0  0
foo T   A   i   0  0  NA 0
foo T   C   o   NA NA 0  0 

num = 0.5 

df<-function(dataframe,num)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include a description of the problem in English and expected output corresponding to the posted input.

Comment: Where do you call `parse()`?

Comment: The code in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57482304/unable-to-parse-data-in-r/57482491#57482491) does not give errors, there is something else going on.